# Float required : [Python 2.7]

Tags: python-2.7, math, floating-point

Error:  c = float(math.sqrt(num))
TypeError: a float is required

Code:

```
def sqrtn(num):
    c = float(math.sqrt(num))
    print "The square root of %s " % c

num = raw_input("Enter the no.")
if choice == 6:
    sqrtn(num)
```

SOLUTION:

```
num = float(raw_input("Enter the no."))
```

Comment: Ignore the if statement

Comment: We do not edit the questions to add “FIXED” or a solution inside the text of the question here. If the solution you ended up using differs significantly from those that were offered, you can write your own answer (and even accept it if you think it's most likely to be useful to someone else). If the solution you ended up using differs only in details from an answer you got, leave a comment below the accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry. Will edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string and you passed it to `sqrt` without converting to `int` or `float`.

You can use a `while` loop in order to ask a number from user until it enters a valid number.

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(raw_input("Enter the no."))
    except ValueError:
        print "Enter a valid number"
    else:
        break

if choice == 6:
    sqrtn(num)
```

Comment: thank you! Fixed it

Comment: @shreydan Good! You can tell this to community by accepting the answer.

Comment: will do it in 10 minutes.